# Inject all implementers of an interface in .NET Core class constructors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

Suppose I have multiple implementations for an interface:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddSingleton<IInterface, ImplementationA>();
    services.AddSingleton<IInterface, ImplementationB>();
    services.AddSingleton<IInterface, ImplementationC>();
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to inject all of them directly in class constructors?

Comment: Create an `IInterfaceCollection` with an implementation that gathers all you `IInterface` implementations and inject that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply it's possible as follows using `IEnumerable` generic class:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo(IEnumerable<IInterface> implementers)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```